# How to pass two parameters in xml for a converter in for a Tuple in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, mvxbind

### For a single input in `.cs` file

```
public class QuesSeriesIndicatorValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, int>
    {
        protected override int Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value)
            {
                return Resource.Drawable.up_arrow;
            }
            else
            {
                return Resource.Drawable.down_arrow;
            }
        }


        protected override bool ConvertBack(int value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return base.ConvertBack(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
        }

    }
```

### From `xml` I pass data as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="2dp">
    <MvxImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        local:MvxBind="DrawableId QuesSeriesIndicator(questionState)" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

Now For an input Where I need to pass two parameters in Xml, I found out we can use `Tuple`.

`Ex::` `public class CruiseShipIndicatorValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<Tuple<bool, bool>, int>`

***How to pass the Data in Xml, similar to***

```
local:MvxBind="DrawableId QuesSeriesIndicator(questionState)"
```

Comment: did you find the solution to this problem?

Comment: Look into this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48765643/3489351
This solves your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can send an object that have the properties that you need, also you converter can be type object, instead int/string/bool, also the value is better if you use an object and cast to the value that you need and return the object(string/int/bool or that you wanted);

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,CultureInfo culture)
{
    var obj = (value as YourObject);
    var yourBool = obj.YourBoolName;
    var yourTuple = obj.YourTuple;
    return thatYouNeed;
}
```

Comment: It `should` be type object, maybe I'm just inexperienced but never seen a converter not be object.

Comment: Yes, have to be type object.